# I want to change the authentication logic of the existing password credential provider

Tags: credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

I built a custom credential provider , this provider is being loaded as an extra sign in option in the windows logon screen and working perfect as expected but I want only that provider to be loaded and not the default password provider. Also I neither want to disable/delete the existing or default system credential providers. In simple words I just want to change the placeholder text and authentication logic of the  password credential provider and if in case my dll gets deleted, the default password provider has to be loaded with no trouble.Can someone tell me how to acheive this or is there any way so that only my provider has to be the only signin option for the user?

Comment: `ICredentialProviderFilter::Filter`

Comment: As @RbMm said, ICredentialProviderFilter ... Old SDK examples have credential filter examples...but in separate DLLs. I'd implement the credpro and filter in the same DLL, that way, in case the credpro DLL got deleted , then the filter would be deleted as well (assuming a file delete and not a registry fiasco). Also, putting them in the same DLL means they can share the same runtime if you link statically because you don't want the burden of distributing other runtimes.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing placing both filter and credpro in the same dll

Comment: how to change the placeholder text of the password field, I have already placed one in common.h but I want to change it for every user based on a condition check , iam trying to change it in initialize method but it is not changing. Can you please answer this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same here, have you come up with a solution?